# Is an EMP weapon a real threat to power grids?

Tags: electromagnetic, power-grid

I do not see how an EMP is realizable.  The idea is a nuclear bomb detonated high enough will release a strong enough EMP to take out a country's power grid without damaging infrastructure.  In my current state of ignorance this does not seem plausible and here is why:

The event will act as an Isotropic Antenna. The Power Density formula of this antenna is Pd = Pt/(4·π·R<sup>2</sup>), where Pt is power transmitted and R = distance from transmission in meters.  Therefore, at 10 meters, the Pd (Power density) will be attenuated 100 times. At 10000 meters, we get attenuation up to 100x10<sup>6</sup>. To have an effective EMP, the bomb would have to be detonated so close, the bomb itself would do more damage than the EMP. The EMP would not even be a factor in such an event. Please correct me where I am misunderstanding.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse#Generation you can see from this that its more complicated than just "the bomb makes a large radio signal"

Comment: The US exploded a bomb at high altitude in the 1960s in an operation called "Starfish Prime". It took out streetlights 1500 km away in Hawaii and destroyed 9 satellites in orbit. With so much more electronics today 60+ years later and probably weapons optimized to cause damage..

Comment: Thank you both for these responses.  I was not aware of Starfish Prime.  I will add that the power grid did not go down, low voltage applications were damaged not high voltage.   The satellites were damaged by radiation not EMP.  My concern is with high voltage power grids.  Any evidence of this being damaged?

Comment: Which EMP type(s)? Conventional EMP bombs are fairly localized, yes; nuclear can be very generalized, and extremely intense at that, enough to be a problem for the power grid. There's also very slow changing phenomena like solar flares which might not be very "pulsey" but due to the scale of the grid, have significant effect.

Comment: NEMP has a 3-stage effect involving multiple sources of EMFI, including direct gamma ionisation, neutron bombardment, and intense disruption of the geomagnetic field. Trying to measure it as a simple electromagnetic emitter is fraught; I think the flaw in your attenuation logic is the assumption that the source of EMFI is a point at the center of the blast, rather than distributed emissions from ionisation of materials, caused by both incident gamma waves and secondary gamma emission through neutron bombardment.

Comment: Apart from all the better points above... your instinct for what is a lot of attenuation is no match for the energy output of a bomb. The concern is not melting of the power cables, it's damage to the computers that control the grid. Your skin integrates the optical power over the whole fireball event, but a semiconductor junction can be damaged in microseconds. It could be harmed a lot further away than a "safe distance" for people. 1 megaton is 4E15 joules, which is 8 kJ/m2 at 200 km (not all radio of course). A typical ESD spark is << 1 J.